# Apply if-else function row-wise

Tags: r

I have the below matrix:

```
structure(c("G", "G", "A", "C", "G", "G", "A", "A", "G", "A", 
"A", "A", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", 
"1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"1", "1", "0", "0", "0"), .Dim = c(6L, 22L), .Dimnames = list(
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), c("allele1", "allele2", 
"s1a", "s1b", "s2a", "s2b", "s3a", "s3b", "s4a", "s4b", "s5a", 
"s5b", "s6a", "s6b", "s7a", "s7b", "s8a", "s8b", "s9a", "s9b", 
"s10a", "s10b")))
```

Which looks like this:

```
  allele1 allele2 s1a s1b s2a s2b s3a s3b s4a s4b s5a s5b s6a s6b s7a s7b s8a s8b s9a s9b s10a s10b
1 "G"     "A"     "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0"  "0" 
2 "G"     "A"     "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1"  "1" 
3 "A"     "G"     "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "1" "1" "0" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "1" "1" "1" "0" "1"  "1" 
4 "C"     "A"     "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0"  "0" 
5 "G"     "A"     "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0"  "0" 
6 "G"     "A"     "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0"  "0"
```

How could I look in each row and replace the occurrences of 0 with the value in column `allele1`, and the occurrences of 1 with the value in column `allele2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do straight logical replacement.  It takes a few lines of code, but would work fine.  The idea is to replicate the first and second columns for the number of columns we are replacing.  We can do that with e.g. `m[, c(1, 1, 1, 1)]`, replicating the first column four times.  This uses no loops.

```
## find the zeros
is0 <- m[, -(1:2)] == 0
## replace the values by replicating the relevant columns
## then applying the logical subset
m[, -(1:2)][is0] <- m[, rep(1, ncol(m)-2)][is0]
m[, -(1:2)][!is0] <- m[, rep(2, ncol(m)-2)][!is0]
```

resulting in the modified `m`

```
m
#   allele1 allele2 s1a s1b s2a s2b s3a s3b s4a s4b s5a s5b s6a s6b s7a s7b s8a s8b s9a s9b s10a s10b
# 1 "G"     "A"     "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "A" "G" "G" "G" "G" "A" "G" "G"  "G" 
# 2 "G"     "A"     "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "A"  "A" 
# 3 "A"     "G"     "G" "A" "G" "A" "A" "G" "G" "A" "A" "G" "A" "G" "A" "A" "G" "G" "G" "A" "G"  "G" 
# 4 "C"     "A"     "C" "C" "C" "C" "A" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "A" "C" "C" "C" "A" "C"  "C" 
# 5 "G"     "A"     "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "A" "G" "G" "G" "G" "A" "G" "G"  "G" 
# 6 "G"     "A"     "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "A" "G" "G" "G" "G"  "G"
```

Comment: Option 2 is similar to the logic of mine, and may well be faster i'm guessing.

Comment: Yours is quite interesting.  Took me a minute to figure it out.  But it definitely doesn't do all the replications I do here.  I would guess they're about even in speed.

Comment: Sorry Richard, option 1 doesn't seem to work as expected (try it out and compare the output with that from option 2). It's been bugging me for a few days now. Option 2 works perfectly well (it's the one I've used).

Comment: @PeterQ - I've taken Option 1 out until I have more time to figure it out.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

One easy to read option would be to use an `apply()` function.  In the code below, I assume that your sample matrix is stored in a variable called `x`:

```
# replace "0" with allele1
x <- apply(x, 1, function(x) {
                    x[x == "0"] <- x[1]
                    return(x)
                 })

# replace "1" with allele2
x <- apply(x, 1, function(x) {
                    x[x == "1"] <- x[2]
                    return(x)
                 })
```

Comment: It's not useful in any way to anonymously downvote a working answer.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I had initially done the same as you but was wanting something more magical like Richard's.

Comment: Richard's solution is certainly magical, but I'll leave this posted in case someone wants a more easily readable answer.

Comment: In the past I have downvoted answers that 'worked' but were extremely obfuscated (i.e. - 'not useful' as per downvote guidelines), but this is certainly not the case here.

Answer (score 4):

Break it down to chunks and avoid row-by-row operations:

```
df <- as.data.frame(df,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df[-(1:2)] <- lapply(df[-(1:2)], as.numeric )

zerosel <- which(df[-(1:2)]==0, arr.ind=TRUE)
onesel  <- which(df[-(1:2)]==1, arr.ind=TRUE)

df[-(1:2)][zerosel] <- df$allele1[zerosel[,1]]
df[-(1:2)][onesel]  <- df$allele2[onesel[,1]]


#  allele1 allele2 s1a s1b s2a s2b s3a s3b s4a s4b s5a s5b s6a s6b ...
#1       G       A   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   A ...
#2       G       A   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G ...
#3       A       G   G   A   G   A   A   G   G   A   A   G   A   G ...
#4       C       A   C   C   C   C   A   C   C   C   C   C   C   C ...
#5       G       A   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   A ...
#6       G       A   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G   G ...
```